# Best Practices for RSpec expect raise_error

Tags: ruby, exception, rspec

I have some code for RSpec.
My (or not my) Class can (or not) call specific exception.
Ex, Class::Foo::Bar::TimeOutError.
I want check it.

```
describe :describe_description do
  before :all do
    object = Class.new
    # method can be call Class::Foo::Bar::TimeOutError
    object.method
  end
  it :exception do
    expect {}.to_not raise_error Class::Foo::Bar::TimeOutError
  end
end
```

This code worked, but RSpec write a Warning:

> WARNING: Using `expect { }.not_to raise_error(SpecificErrorClass)` risks false positives, since literally any other error would cause the expectation to pass, including those raised by Ruby (e.g. NoMethodError, NameError and ArgumentError), meaning the code you are intending to test may not even get reached. Instead consider using `expect {}.not_to raise_error` or `expect { }.to raise_error(DifferentSpecificErrorClass)`. This message can be suppressed by setting: `RSpec::Expectations.configuration.on_potential_false_positives = :nothing`.

How can I fix my code so that the RSpec works correctly and does not issue warnings?

Comment: Passing specific error class is useful when you expect some kind of an error. There is no obvious reason to test specific error to not be raised, since you do not want any errors to be raised during the execution. `expect {}.to_not raise_error` is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a way to apply `expect {}.to_not raise_error` in the spec without this warning (that's the whole point of adding this warning).

It doesn't make sense logically because you don't need to explicitly check a type of error is not raised.

**Scenario 1**. The code executes successfully (i.e no errors at all). Then a passing test itself implies there's no `Class::Foo::Bar::TimeOutError` thrown.

**Scenario 2**. Another type of error is thrown. Then `expect {}.to_not raise_error Class::Foo::Bar::TimeOutError` isn't testing anything, it still just passes which creates false positive.

**Scenario 3**. If you really want to use it, suppress with the setting `on_potential_false_positives` then the test will continue without the warning. If it passes, then this has no difference with the scenario which makes `expect {}.to_not raise_error` redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For a future-proof solution I recommend setting

```
RSpec::Expectations.configuration.on_potential_false_positives = :raise
```

And fixing any offending examples from

```
expect { some_call }.to not_raise_error(SomeErrorClass)
```

to

```
expect { some_call }.to not_raise_error
# OR
expect { some_call }.to raise_error(SomeOtherErrorClass)
```